# Wordspacing of justify block

Tags: html, css, styles, justify

i want some `text-align:justify` blocks but with same word-spacing between them.

Did someone has a solution for that?

I tried it with a negative word-spacing but it was not the solution.

```
text-align:justify;
word-spacing:-1px;
```

thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't set negative values when the text is setted as `justify`. You have to set an higher value like `10px`.

Choose between those 3 solutions:

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;  
}

.word-spacing {
  word-spacing: 10px;
}

.both {
  text-align: justify;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="justify"><b>Justify</b><br>
  Continually architect user-centric products for interactive experiences. Authoritatively supply goal-oriented meta-services without one-to-one synergy. Monotonectally formulate bleeding-edge ROI before fully tested networks. Authoritatively fabricate leading-edge infrastructures for enabled solutions. Competently communicate open-source total linkage before.
</p>

<p class="word-spacing"><b>Word Spacing Only</b><br>
  Continually architect user-centric products for interactive experiences. Authoritatively supply goal-oriented meta-services without one-to-one synergy. Monotonectally formulate bleeding-edge ROI before fully tested networks. Authoritatively fabricate leading-edge infrastructures for enabled solutions. Competently communicate open-source total linkage before.
</p>

<p class="both"><b>Justfy + Word Spacing</b><br>
  Continually architect user-centric products for interactive experiences. Authoritatively supply goal-oriented meta-services without one-to-one synergy. Monotonectally formulate bleeding-edge ROI before fully tested networks. Authoritatively fabricate leading-edge infrastructures for enabled solutions. Competently communicate open-source total linkage before.
</p>
```